Metric entropy for the parametric family $1-e^{-\theta x}$
Consider the parametric class of function
$$
f_\theta (x) = 1-e^{-\theta x}
$$
defined on the interval $[0, 1]$, and $\theta \in [0,1]$.
Using the sup-norm, we can bound the $\delta$-covering number $N(\delta)$ of the class of function by
$$
1 + \lfloor \frac{1-1/e}{2\delta} \rfloor \leq N(\delta) \leq \frac{1}{2\delta} + 2,
$$
(See example 5.9 Wainwright's textbook on HDS.)
My question is, how to show that
the asymptotic rate of $\log N(\delta)$ is $\log \frac{1}{\delta}$ in this example, i.e.,
$$
\log N(\delta) \asymp \log \frac{1}{\delta}.
$$
In particular, I want to show that there exist constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$ A \leq \frac{\log N(\delta)}{\log \frac{1}{\delta}} \leq B,$$
as $\delta \to 0$.

Where exactly are you stuck? This seems as if one just needs to apply several quite easy estimates.

@PhoemueX I want to know how to get the last asymptotic bound from the first inequality? I do not see why the limit holds using the first inequality
